# Link module from external file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on new project and I want to use two modules placed in separated files. Unfortunetaly, when I try to declare second in my root one I receive an error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

So, here is my root file, app.js:

```
var beerMe = angular.module("beerMe", ["admin", "ngRoute"])

.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "../views/home/home.html",
        controller: "MyCtrl"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/home"
    })
}])

.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

And second one, which I want to bind, admin.js:

```
var admin = angular.module("admin", ["firebase", "ngRoute"]);

admin.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/add.html",
        controller: "AdminCtrl"
    }).when ("/edit", {
        templateUrl: "views/edit.html",
        controller: "AdminCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    })
}]);

admin.controller("AdminCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
   // my code goes here

}]);
```

In admin.js I connnect to firebase and I want to have access to all data from my module "beerMe".

I'd be very grateful if you could help me to figure out why there's a problem with binding these two.

Comment: Could you add info about how and where you referenced these files?

Comment: I've done it here, in first line on app.js: var beerMe = angular.module("beerMe", ["admin", "ngRoute"]). "admin" is a name of second module.

Comment: Okay, but where are they referenced in HTML? For example, you should have `admin.js` referenced with some script tag somewhere. Could you post where did you reference `app.js` and `.admin.js` in HTML?

Comment: why you need to define 2 modules, just define a single module under the name `beerMe` and include `firebase` in the array. And also you can define all your routes in the app.js file

Comment: @eminlala, I added in my HTML simple reference <script src=""></script> for admin.js and app.js.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri, it's because admin.js is for my admin panel and I want to keep my code modular.

Comment: Check if app.js script is loaded before admin.js. If it is, just switch the order.

Comment: @eminlala, I've changed order, but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var admin = angular.module("admin", ["firebase", "ngRoute"]);`

to `var admin = angular.module("admin");`

and change `root` module like this

```
var beerMe = angular.module("beerMe", ["admin", "ngRoute", "firebase"])
```

Comment: can you share how you wrote, ng-app? Is it ng-app="beerMe" or ng-app="admin"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dependencies are the wrong way round. Having `admin` as a dependency of `beerMe` will *not* make the `beerMe` module available in your `admin` module.

If you want your `admin` module to be able to access data from inside the `beerMe` module then `beerMe` should be a dependency of `admin`.

```
var admin = angular.module('admin', ['firebase', 'ngRoute', 'beerMe']);
```

Comment: Yes, I also have tried that. But when I switch it like that, my html with ng-app="admin" receives error and html with ng-app="beerMe" works.

Comment: Does each module use services/controllers from the other?

Comment: I think so. I want to insert data from admin controller to HTML, which is defined as ng-app="beerMe".

Comment: It sounds like you have circular dependencies. I'd consider looking at each of your modules and seeing if you can identify the third concern.